# could not find add() method that takes a JButton and BorderLayout.SOUTH constant

Tags: java, swing

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
JButton button = new JButton();
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
```

guys, i tried to look into the API but could not find this particular add() method which takes the above argument of BorderLayout and button. I Checked the Superclasses "Container", "Component" and all but could not find this method. Where is it defined?

Comment: "_which takes the above argument of BorderLayout and button_" `BorderLayout.SOUTH` is a String.

Comment: That is an old obsolete method (since java 1.1) and should not be used. Instead you should use: `add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END)`. where the second parameter is an Object so each layout manager can use a custom constraint if required.

Comment: But aren't this however obsolete method supposed to be in the API?